# Simple PyPDF exercise - AttributeError: 'NullObject' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, pypdf

Working on a simple PyPDF related exercise - I basically need to take a PDF file and apply a watermark to to it.

Here's my code:

```
# We need to build a program that will watermark all of our PDF files
# Use the wtr.pdf and apply it to all of the pages of our PDF file

import PyPDF2

# Open the file we want to add the watermark to
with open("combined.pdf", mode="rb") as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)

    # Open the watermark file and get the watermark 
    with open("wtr.pdf", mode="rb") as watermark_file:
        watermark_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(watermark_file)        

        # Create a writer object for the output file
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()        

        for i in range(reader.numPages):
            page = reader.getPage(i)
            # Merge the watermark page object into our current page
            page.mergePage(watermark_reader.getPage(0))
            # Append this new page into our writer object
            writer.addPage(page)

        with open("watermarked.pdf", mode="wb") as output_file:
            writer.write(output_file)
```

I am unclear as to why I get this error:

```
$ python watermark.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "watermark.py", line 20, in <module>
    page.mergePage(watermark_reader.getPage(0))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2239, in mergePage
    self._mergePage(page2)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2260, in _mergePage
    new, newrename = PageObject._mergeResources(originalResources, page2Resources, res)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2170, in _mergeResources
    newRes.update(res1.get(resource, DictionaryObject()).getObject())
AttributeError: 'NullObject' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I would appreciate any insights. I have been staring at this for a while.

Comment: Make sure the pdf is in the same directory as your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. They are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your pdf file doesn't contain "/Resources". PyPDF2 tries to get it in line 2314 in https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2314

You can try another pdf file to check if the error persists. May be it is a bug in the library or the library doesn't support such files.

Another thing I noticed is that line numbers in master branch of the library do not match line numbers in your stack trace, so may be you need to get more recent version of the library and hope that the problem is fixed there.

---

By briefly looking at [pdf file structure](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/pdf-explained/9781449321581/ch04.html) it seems that /Resources are optional. If this is a case, then PyPDF2 doesn't handle this case and it should be probably reported as a bug at https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues

Comment: Update. I tried updating to PyPDF3 but got the same error. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It seems that PyPDF3 is just an old fork of PyPDF2 and is not a reasonable version to update to.